# Simplest AC-DC: charging capacitor at needed AC input voltage

Tags: ac-dc

To implement a simple AC mains input circuit to charge a capacitor with low voltage DC I think that it should be possible to connect the output capacitor to the AC line through a diode, and a transistor which will disconnect the capacitor from AC line after the input AC sine will go higher than some certain voltage (Uthr on the picture). So the power will be consumed from the input AC line only within narrow periods of time when the AC voltage is higher than the current capacitor voltage and lower than some certain limitation (let's say 30 Volts):

[image]

After this "rectifier" an LM7805 or similar IC can be used to stabilize the output voltage.

I suspect that this schematic can be useful in application not demanding for power, efficiency, input to output isolation and power correction factor. However it could be extremely cheap and simple.

If this was already been realized, how can I search for related products (switch driver schematic, special purpose ICs, switches...)?

**UPDATE 1**

I have to say sorry to many of downvoters for my poor English. This was a struggle for me to put my idea into English words.

Comment: Your question assumes a lot of context you haven't provided us. Please take a moment to read it over as if you didn't have all the context you do, then rewrite it so other people can understand it.

Comment: Ok, @NickJohnson! I will put some additional pictures for clarification!

Comment: google non isolated mains power supply circuit

Comment: @JImDearden He is not suggesting a std non-isolated cct - see my answer.

Comment: All: This is a perfectly reasonable question and he describes what he wants well enough. If he has come up with this idea independently it shows very good thinking - not worthy of the close votes.  He is suggesting an offline supply wity a pass "transistor" that is turned o when the AC level is low and turned off when VAC > to >> Vout. The idea works but has too many risks to be 'safe'. Despite thisyou can buy ICs that do it.

Comment: I just re-read the question with a view to editing it for clarity. It's not needed. The English may not be quite what you are used to but he expresses what he intends clearly and well. The technical detail is there, it is correct, and the question is a perfectly fair one. I suggest that the close-voters retract their votes. || Sure - the English here is not quite standard but it can be followed just by taking statements to mean exactly what they say. Presentation this good needs to be able to be dealt with.

Comment: @NickJohnson he assumes nothing and explains everything. The concept is entirely viable and he addresses all the key points. Take it a thought at the times and it should be entirely clear.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I know but I didn't put std (standard) in my search criteria. The O/P did ask "how can I search for **related products**." hence my comment. You have to admit that even your (excellent) answer is a non isolated mains power supply - I rest my case.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I voted to close it and I'm not retracting until the OP supplies the pictures he said. I'll also say this - the requirements listed include turning off the charge cycle as voltage rises above some moderate level - this adds circuit complication and needs to be justified - my suspicion is that it's not a well-thought-thru idea and that a simple capacitor dropper and zener diode circuit would be perfectly adequate for the OP. But he now has a chance to justify turning the transistor off when voltage rises above a certain level. If this is needed then your circuit is cool.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I didn't vote to close, but I still think it's unclear. "the output capacitor", "the diode" - output of what? What circuit is he talking about? I'm glad you were able to guess what he meant, but that doesn't mean the question is clear.

Comment: @Andyaka "Read my pictures".  :-). There are often many circuits that can fill a need, as I know you know. He was NOT asking for an isolated circuit - he was asking for comment on a concept he had thought of. If this is his own independent idea then he has done well indeed. That others thought of it say 50 years ago is not relevant. | I did NOT guess what he wanted - I read what he said and it was entirely clear. And a simple zener and capacitor dropper has different characteristics.If you don't mind doing violence to power factor this cct can supply VERY substantial current. ....

Comment: @Andy ... If everyone close voted a question after somebody asked them to do something then few would be those who found the narrow path as they may quite reasonably not attend to such a request for hours or even a few days for various reasons.

Comment: @NickJohnson THe capacitor is the one in the subject line. I do not like the practice BUT many people have the subject line as the start of a sentence which continues into the text. | As I noted to Andy -  I did not guess what he meant - i read what he wrtote and it said what he meant.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I had two reasons to close the question. Both were mentioned. The clarity of the question was also poor but I believed I understood it.

Comment: All: Please see my UPDATE 1 and the picture I have put for question clarification.

Comment: @Andyaka He's provided the diagram. | The clarity was good and I was sure I understood it. | He was not asking the best way to make a simple (or other) non isolated supply. He was asking about his concept. So the "fact" that a series cap supply may be superior was not relevant. | I have no real doubt that you'll disagree with me point by point (and I with you :-) ) BUT I don't know why you would do so in about 1/2 the cases.

Comment: @RomanMatveev can you please justify why this idea is better (or more appropriate) than using a dropper capacitor and zener diode like this: http://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/led-night-lamp.gif

Comment: @Andyaka I recently tried to implement such schematic which I've taken from TDA5051A datasheet (http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TDA5051A.pdf page 15) and both elements (2W resistor and 2uF x 250VAC cap) was pretty big (for my application). Of course I can not be sure that this idea is better. To be sure I need to understand the schematic and BOM first. And actually Russell have mentioned many drawbacks this idea has inside.

Comment: @RomanMatveev Yes I see that circuit and maybe you are right about it being cheaper/smaller. I guess it's a bit too late to change much (other than remove the close vote) but I'd be interested in hearing if you think it could be smaller. Maybe russell will throw in his thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept you describe is implemented both by some commercial IC's and by discrete circuits such as the one below, designed by the great Dave Johnson.

Very briefly:

After mains AC zero crossing positive going rising mains voltage couples to the gate of the MOSFET turning it on. The MOSFET connects the "ground" of the output circuit to the -ve of the input bridge rectifier BR1.  The 470 uF charges to the so-far-still-low mains voltage.
The 220k:10k divider drives the 2N222 transistor base. When the mains voltages rises high enough to to turj on the transistor, the transistor clamps the MOSFET gate to its source, turning it off. This state continues until Vmains again falls below the critical level.

#### NB!

When the MOSFET is OFF the output circuit floats to rectified mains phase voltage above AC "neutral". Touch it and you may die.

Even if the circuit was rearranged so that output earth was at neutral when Vmains was high the circuit would still be a potential death trap.

[image]

Here is a very slightly altered version - same circuit - load wiring shown slightly differently to make it clearer that the whole output circuit is effectively alternately connected to Neutral and then to phase.

- "Interest only" and of not much effect on the output when considered in isolation - When rectified AC in is between *about* 3V and 8V the FET is on and output ground is one diode drop above the most negative AC lead. When Vin_AC > 8V the FET is off and Vout + is one diode drop below the most positive phase lead. So regardless of which input lead is phase and which is neutral, the output effectively "dances" between them every cycle.

[image]

[Above is based on PDF **here**](http://www.discovercircuits.com/PDF-FILES/offline5v.pdf)

For an explanation of this circuit (which effectively does what your idea does) see my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/how-to-efficiently-charge-a-capacitor-from-ac-source)

**Note very carefully that ALL parts or this circuit MUST be treated as if they were at mains voltage - as they may be. This is a very dangerous circuit and must only be used with a full understanding of and allowance for the dangers.**

Circuits like this are prone to occasional sudden noisy & explosive failure with release of magic smoke. Mains spikes or dips or surges can "fool" the switching logic in various ways. While the concept is good the risk is so high that use of safer isolated supplies is almost always preferred. Even if the user is not endangered the circuit is liable to destroy the powered equipment "just because it can".

Comment: I'm hearty thank you for a) understanding right the main idea of the question 2) for answering one c) for the words you have said to protect my inarticulated question. I tried to put some additional info to make it a bit clearer.